# Print Data Frame with long string variables

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I have a data frame which contains descriptions of survey questions which can be quite long. I am trying to figure out a way to neatly print them. Here's an example:

```
foo <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, 
                  v2 = rep(c("This is a really long description of a survey question that gives a bunch of information about the question and can be very long blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"), 5), 
                  v3 = 6:10)
```

I would like the printed output to look something like this:

```
  v1   v2                                       v3
1  1   This is a really long description of     6
       a survey question that gives a bunch 
       of information about the question and
       can be very long blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
2  2   This is a really long description of     7
       a survey question that gives a bunch 
       of information about the question and
       can be very long blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
3  3   This is a really long description of     8
       a survey question that gives a bunch 
       of information about the question and
       can be very long blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
4  4   This is a really long description of     9
       a survey question that gives a bunch 
       of information about the question and
       can be very long blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
5  5   This is a really long description of     10
       a survey question that gives a bunch 
       of information about the question and
       can be very long blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Comment: I haven't come across a way to print this way in the console itself. But there are a few ways to output HTML tables to the viewer that do this, e.g. `flextable::flextable(foo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flextable::flextable(foo, cwidth = c(0.5,7,0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you. I did not realize that you could make tables this way and display them in the viewer. Very good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abbreviate()` and `DT::datatable()`. That way you can shorten the text automatically and see the full text on click:

```
library(DT)
texts <- paste0(1:5, "is is a really long description of a survey question that gives a bunch of information about the question and can be very long blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah")

foo <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5, 
                  v2 = paste0('<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'', texts, '\');">', 
                              abbreviate(texts, named = FALSE), '</a>'), 
                  v3 = 6:10)
datatable(foo, escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This was a great solution, and will probably help me do some other things in the future. However, I accepted the other answer because it did not require changing the data frame. Just for my general knowledge, do you know if it is possible to make a table using this that the user can interact with and change the data frame? For instance could you compare to possible values for the same observation in a data frame and select one of the two and have it be modified in the data frame?

Comment: you can change values in datatable,...it is editable,...Interaction could be made possible with shiny. If you would like to discuss it deeper, a new question would be a good option, i think.

Comment: This is good to know. I'm not to the point in my project where I need this yet. Once I get there and have a chance to play with datatable some and formulate what my actual question is I will post a new question if I need to. Thanks